# Fade in / Out div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fade

So I have some javascript for a website but at the moment the only way I can get it to work is if it is mixed in with the HTML. I've read this is bad practice, but I can't figure out how to get it to work as a script in the head section. Can anyone help me out? I have read tonnes of similar questions on here but can't get it to work.

Thank you, 
Alex

Here's the code I have:

```
<li><a href="#" class="about_button" onclick="$('.about_background, .about_close').fadeIn('fast') ">About</a></li>
```

I'm then fading it out again by adding:

```
<a href="#" class="about_close" onclick="$('.about_background').fadeOut('fast')"></a>
```

and having a div that spans the width and height of the page so the user can click anywhere, not sure if this is a good way and is alright to use.

Thanks

Comment: What are you putting in <head>?

Comment: so it is ok to mix it in with the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html you can place the elements:

```
<li><a href="#" class="about_button">About</a></li>
<a href="#" class="about_close"></a>
```

and then at the bottom of the body put a reference to a js file (it should be at the bottom of the file rather than in the head so that the html loads first and the elements are ready when you use js to bind event handlers to them)

```
<script src="<file path>"></script>
```

In an external js file you can bind the event handler to them:

```
$(".about_button").click(function(){
   $('.about_background, .about_close').fadeIn('fast') 
}
$(".about_close").click(function(){
   $('.about_background').fadeOut('fast')
}
```

Comment: @AlexDelis yeah that should work by itself if you put it at the bottom of the body area.  If you put it in the header you will have to wrap it in a document.ready function to make sure the dom elements are loaded before you try to bind click handlers to them. That would look something like I3B13's answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forget to use the document ready.

The code you need:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.about_button').click(function(){ $('.about_background, .about_close').fadeIn('fast'); });
      $('.about_close').click(function(){ $('.about_background').fadeOut('fast'); });
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: This works, but it really should ideally be in an external file rather than just a script tag.  And if you put the script at the end of the body rather than in the head, the document.ready is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>
```

In HTML 5 you dont need to specify the type, else you need to specify type="text/javascript"

Comment: ah ok so I am fine mixing it in with HTML as long as in put it in a .js file and link it?

Comment: If your javascript/jQuery works, thats al you have to do indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery selectors to target your HTML elements and put listeners on them:

```
$('.about_button').on('click', function() {
    $('.about_background, .about_close').fadeIn('fast')
})
```

`$('.about_button')` is the selector you use to target the element.
`on('click'` sets an onclick listener on the targeted element
`function() { ... }` is the callback function that'll get called when the listener gets triggered